# How to add attachment in RFC822 format MAIL using Google API?

Tags: c#, email

I am trying to add **attachment in RFC822 format MAIL** using Google API (c#).

Referring to this link

http://code.google.com/apis/apps/email_migration/developers_guide_dotnet.html

How should i start?

Can anyone give me sample mail value?

Is there any study material or documentation available on net.To understand 
**Google Apps Email Migration API**.

Comment: What does app engine have to do with it?  App engine does not support C# as far as I know.

Comment: Agreed - there's a difference between Google App Engine and the Google API.  I retagged the question, since this deals with the API (of which there is a C# client library, though it covers nowhere close to the entire breadth of the Google API).

Answer (score 1):

There's a disconnect between what you're asking and what you want.  Specifically, [RFC 822](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc822.html) doesn't recognize attachments.  As far as RFC 822 is concerned, an email is just a set of headers followed by the message body.  There are several other RFC's you'll want to look at to see exactly how attachments are stored in email ([989](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc989.html), [1421](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1421.html), [2822](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2822.html), and probably some others).

But the upshot is that you shouldn't have to worry about it.  Simply take the entire raw message and put it in a CDATA section within the `apps:rfc822Msg` element.  A sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
    xmlns:batch="http://schemas.google.com/gdata/batch"
    xmlns:gd="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005">
  <entry>
    <category term="http://schemas.google.com/apps/2006#mailItem" scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind" />
    <apps:rfc822Msg xmlns:apps="http://schemas.google.com/apps/2006">
      <![CDATA[MIME-Version: 1.0
Received: by 10.143.9.6 with HTTP; Fri, 26 Feb 2010 08:11:48 -0800 (PST)
Date: Fri, 26 Feb 2010 10:11:48 -0600
Delivered-To: joschmo@gmail.com
Message-ID: <4a3140f1002260811v6c539c42rda718def8bb7e168@mail.gmail.com>
Subject: Example
From: Joe Schmo <joschmo@gmail.com>
To: joschmo@gmail.com
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=000e0cd2dd1216bdff04808328cb

--000e0cd2dd1216bdff04808328cb
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=000e0cd2dd1216bdf404808328c9

--000e0cd2dd1216bdf404808328c9
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1

This is the message body text.

--000e0cd2dd1216bdf404808328c9
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1

This is the message body text.

--000e0cd2dd1216bdf404808328c9--
--000e0cd2dd1216bdff04808328cb
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=US-ASCII; name="test.txt"
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="test.txt"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
X-Attachment-Id: f_g656ktq20

VGhpcyBpcyBhIHRlc3Q=
--000e0cd2dd1216bdff04808328cb--]]>
    </apps:rfc822Msg>
    <apps:mailItemProperty value="IS_STARRED"
      xmlns:apps="http://schemas.google.com/apps/2006" />
    <apps:mailItemProperty value="IS_UNREAD"
      xmlns:apps="http://schemas.google.com/apps/2006" />
    <apps:label labelName="Event Invitations"
      xmlns:apps="http://schemas.google.com/apps/2006" />
    <apps:label labelName="Friends"
      xmlns:apps="http://schemas.google.com/apps/2006" />
    <batch:id>0</batch:id>
  </entry>
</feed>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're migrating messages I assume you have access to the original raw message, which should have everything in place already (all attachments correctly encoded for email transmission). If that's the case you just need to follow the example in [Migrating Email Messages](http://code.google.com/apis/apps/email_migration/developers_guide_dotnet.html#MailItems) where `rfcTextOfMessage` is the full raw message you want to migrate.